# In the future will DOCX be as readable RTF

Tags: ms-word, word-2013

My default file format is RTF because I mostly use Word 2013 to write diary entries. I thought RTF would be a format that should be readable by most computers for years to come. Can the same be said about the native Word DOCX format? I was thinking of switching to DOCX as my native format because it gets rid of “[Compatibility Mode]” warnings in the title bar and taskbar and the files are smaller. Maybe there are other advantages too.

I imagine TXT files would be the most universal file format for a diary, but I use basic formatting and tables in my entries. I worry that 20 years in the future I'll be importing my diary in whatever word processor exists then and I won't be able to read them.

Comment: Hmmm my crystal ball is too scratched to see what will happen in 20 years :). DOCX is officially documented format - you should be able to create reader for it even if you are the last on the planet... (But really SO is not a good place for future forecast questions).

Comment: This question is not about programming, so it needs to be asked somewhere else. But nobody will be able to look 20 years into the future. Perhaps html or PDF are a better choice for you

Comment: You might consider some variant of Markdown. You can add formatting to the rendered versions but still have the source human-readable in any text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your worry is quite well-founded, and actually has a name: digital rot. It applies to file formats, but just as much to storage media and other things. My Master's thesis is now inaccessible to me because I only have it on floppy disk, and also because the programming language I used is no longer available.

On the other hand, IF I really needed access to it, I probably could (buying a floppy drive off eBay, finding an emulator for the ancient computer it was created for, finding the programming language, and reading the data are likely all still doable today).

As for your specific question: RTF may not be your best choice, because it, too, is a proprietary format with many different, and sometimes incompatible, flavors - and on top of that, it is outdated and no longer supported.

My personal favorite format for this type of storage is either TXT if formatting does not matter, HTML if formatting does matter, and PDF if HTML's formatting is not enough.

TXT is likely going to be with us for a very long time - probably for at least your and my lifetime. There just is too much software source code written in it for it to go away.

HTML is also going to be with us for a very long time, although incompatibilities will develop as older features are being dropped.

PDF is a proprietary format and could disappear, although the installed base means that it probably will remain readable for decades. The main advantage of PDF is that it makes it easy to print to paper - or, with the appropriate printer driver, print to whatever file format will take its place.

DOCX is likely going to be Microsoft's last Word file format, and will be around at least as long as Microsoft offers word.

Bottom line: your concern is justified, but in the end, you do have a number of options.